# Proving $1/(2+x_n)$ is a contractive sequence and find its limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have $x_1 > 0$, and $x_{n+1} = 1/(2+x_n)$

So I'm trying to prove that it is contractive, so far I have:

$$|x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}| = |1/(2+x_{n+1}) - 1/(2+x_n)| = |(x_n - x_{n+1}) / (2+x_{n+1})(2+x_n)|$$

but I'm stuck and don't know how to simplify further. I know that I want a constant $C$ such that $0 < C < 1$.

I then need to try and find the limit of the sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}| = \left | \frac{1}{(2+x_{n+1})} - \frac{1}{(2+x_n)}\right| = \frac{|(x_n - x_{n+1})|} { (2+x_{n+1})(2+x_n)}\leq\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)|(x_n - x_{n+1})|$,(because minimum value of $x_n$ cannot be less than 0.)

hence,sequence is contractive.
and every contractive sequence converges.

To find its limit let $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=l$ then apply it on both sides of $x_{n+1} = 1/(2+x_n)$.